# How Android checks APK certificate at runtime?

Tags: android, certificate, apk, digital-signature

I have read everything regarding app signing at http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html.

We are designing a Platform based on open source Android OS and there's a business requirement that only apps signed by our private key shall be installed on the device. Currently on my Android phone and tablet, I can install any APK (it doesn't matter if it was self signed  using debug key or a private key). How can we make the business team happy?

On my phone I see Settings->Security->Install from device storage (under Credential storage) what is this? Is there a way I can upload my private key on a device and Android will automatically validate the APK?

Comment: You can't, unless you build a custom version of Android.

Comment: Yes, we're developing a custom version of Android OS.

Comment: Then the easiest way would be to remove the options for "Install from device storage" and "Install from unknown sources" from the settings UI.

Comment: Will that be CDD compliant?

Comment: Well, you can read that as well as I can ;)  But I imagine removing settings options which do not fundamentally affect the hardware and software should be OK.